# Пересчитать все файлы и узнать их размер в папке по расширению

Tags: файлы, администрирование, powershell

Нужно пересчитать все файлы по расширениям и узнать их общий размер и выввести. Например:

- exe - 100500 files - 100500 MB
- docx - 100500 files - 100500 MB

Мой код много раз выводит список расширений, не понимаю в чем проблема. Как это можно исправить?

```
 $FileExtensionArray = Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\ -Recurse -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | sort extension -Unique | Group-Object psparentpath, extension | ft -AutoSize @{Expression={($_.Name -split ", .")[1]};Label="Extension"} 
$i = ($FileExtensionArray).count
for ($j=0; $j -lt $i; $j++)
 {
    $FilelSize = (Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Include *.$FileExtensionArray[$j] | Measure -property length -sum);
    $FileExtensionArray + " (total)" + " — " + (Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\ -recurse -force -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).count + " files" + " - " + "{0:N2}" -f ($FilelSize.sum / 1MB) + "MB";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обрабатывать можно еще сам массив циклом `foreach`, пример:

```
$FileExtensionArray = (Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\ -Recurse -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | sort extension -Unique).Extension
foreach ($f in $FileExtensionArray)
{
   $FilelSize = (Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Include "*$f" | Measure -property length -sum);
   $f + " - " + $FilelSize.count + " files" + " - " + "{0:N2}" -f ($FilelSize.sum / 1MB) + "MB";
}
```

Отвечая на вопрос:

> Мой код много раз выводит список расширений, не понимаю в чем
>   проблема. Как это можно исправить?

Тип значений в вашем массиве:

```
 $FileExtensionArray = Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\ -Recurse -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | sort extension -Unique | Group-Object psparentpath, extension | ft -AutoSize @{Expression={($_.Name -split ", .")[1]};Label="Extension"} 


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $FileExtensionArray[1].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
False    False    GroupStartData                           Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.StartData
```

Вызов 
$FileExtensionArray + " (total)" + " происходит без обращения к ячейки массива
вызов должен выглядеть $FileExtensionArray[$j], после этого получаем ошибку из за формата данных в массиве, поэтому конвертируем данные в $FileExtensionArray[$j].toString()

Получаем что-то похожее

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData (total) — 6327 files - 0,00MB
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData (total) — 6327 files - 0,00MB
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData (total) — 6327 files - 0,00MB
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData (total) — 6327 files - 0,00MB
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData (total) — 6327 files - 0,00MB
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData (total) — 6327 files - 0,00MB
```

Ввиду этого правильнее собрать массив так

`(Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\ -Recurse -File -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | sort extension -Unique).Extension -replace ",.*"`

P.S. Уверен, что у кого либо найдется более изящное решение, я только учусь.